# Opera list item (li) hover background color

Tags: css, hover, opera

This is a pretty weird problem. I'm not sure if its a problem with my CSS or with the Opera browser. This issue only appears in opera, tested in safari, ie 10, chrome, and firefox. So, I have a dropdown menu and when I hover over one of the items on the menu (which is an li), it does not fully get highlighted.

Here's a pic of what happens when I hover over it:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvQRd.png

This is my css:

```
ul{ 
    list-style:none;
position:absolute;
background:#656665;
font-size:32px;
color:#0495CF;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
display:none;}
 li{
    padding:5px;
 }
 li:hover
 {
    background:gray;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:5px;
 }
```

Comment: What version of Opera?

Comment: opera 12.16, supposedly the latest version

Comment: Live example please, http://jsfiddle.net/ or something.

Comment: What styles did you put on the '<a>' tag? If any.